# Draft Items in Document library get hidden from everyone?

Tags: document-library

I have this really strange thing, I can't sort out. I developed this document library with some customization like ECT columns etc. So I saved it as template and when I use that template to create another document library like that. It does not allow anyone - even the user who created that file to view it in the document library. I have checked in the Document library settings that "Any user who can read items " is selected. But it just hides the file still.

Now this is not the case in the document library I originally created. So I'm really out of clues right now. Could anyone please tell me if they have experienced this before and what to do with it?

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 SP1 and office 2010.
BR,
Imran

Comment: Does the default view have any filters on it?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out myself. The solution is kind of funny in the sense that this is a bug in SharePoint, or at least in our installation of SharePoint. To solve this, we just go to the Document Library settings, the versioning settings and the option of "Any user who can read items" is already selected so we just press OK and it starts to work just fine.